# how to list user tables alone in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

for the  below four query getting user defined object name as well, system related object name i need only user defined object name. For that what i do?

```
select trigger_name from user_triggers;
select TABLE_NAME from user_tables
select view_NAME from user_views
select table_name constraint_NAME from user_constraints;
```

first query results will be like this.

```
DEF$_PROPAGATOR_TRIG
REPCATLOGTRIG
TRG   (user defined)
TRIG1 (user defined)
TRIG3 (user defined)
```

i need only last three trigger names. is there any way?

thanks
ganesh

Comment: hm, dont have an oracle db at hand here, but a query against DBA_OBJECTS might give you what you need

Comment: i need objects name that have been created by a user.

Comment: Most catalogs have some field that might be used in a where clause. For instance, select trigger_name from user_triggers where SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN (....). Or perhaps something like WHERE CREATOR_NAME NOT IN (...). etc. What other fields are availble in the Oracle catalogs you are querying, and can you use any of them to filter the results?

Comment: select trigger_name from user_triggers where SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN(user_triggers ); is not working. what to add in parentheses.

Comment: select table_name from user_triggers where schema_name NOT IN('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'MDSYS', 'CTXSYS'); i have tried this one also

Comment: how to retrieve only the tables i have created?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the tables created by someuser

```
select owner
     , object_name
     , object_type
  from ALL_OBJECTS
 where owner = 'someuser' and object_type = 'TABLE';
```